# Fourier Transform Of Fractional Laplacian

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

[Fourier Transform Of Fractional Laplacian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDdk5.png)

I dont know why we have the last 2 inequality and why it occurs the characteristics ball B1

Comment: Could you share the book/notes you are using?

Comment: Questions should be as self-contained as possible. References to further sources to provide context are also OK. But if you just point to a Wikipedia article and ask about it, that's no good. E.g. in 2 years that link may just be broken or the content there changed.

Comment: Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces - Enrico Valdinoci